# Exercise of Probability

Tags: probability, statistics

I have this exercise in the calculation of probabilities:
In a binary communication channel, 40% of the time the value 1 is transmitted; the probability of correctly receiving a transmitted 0 value is 0.90 and the probability of correctly receiving the transmitted value 1 is 0.95. Decide
(a) The probability of receiving the value 1.

(b) The probability that the value 1 was transmitted if that was the value received.

Being U = The communication channel transmits the value 1; 
C = The communication channel transmits the value 0;
F = Probability of failure;
From the statement I get

```
Pr (U) = 0.40
Pr (C) = 0.60
Pr ($F^\complement $ | U) = 0.90
Pr ($F^\complement $ | C) = 0.95
```

For a), the statement itself is giving it to me, although with the data I can also calculate it as

```
Pr (U and $F^\complement $) + Pr (U and F) = 0.40
```

For b) they ask me for a conditional     Pr ($F^\complement $ | U)     that they also give it to me as part of the statement.

I was surprised that this exercise is so easy, so I would like someone to confirm if it is good or badly done

Comment: (a) Probability of _receiving_ 1 is sum of probability 1 was sent and properly transmitted plus probability 0 was sent and improperly transmitted. (b) P(1 sent | 1 rec) = P(1 sent & 1 rec) / P(1 sent), where P(1 sent) was found in (a). // Review _General Multiplication Rule for Intersections,_ _Law of Total Probability_ and _Bayes' Theorem._

Comment: @BruceET
Then, with the notation that I put up being U = 1 is transmitted through the channel
C = 0 is transmitted through the channel and F = is received with malfunction in a) Pr (U) = Pr (U & F ^ c) + Pr (C & F) = 0.44


For b) Pr (F ^ c | U) and applying Bayes the numerator remains Pr Pr (F ^ c & U) = Pr (F ^ c) * Pr (U | F ^ c) and denominator Pr (U) but I do not have Pr (U | F ^ c)

Comment: Answ to (a) seems OK. Notation is awkward. On your own for final answ to (b). P(1 rec & 0 sent) = P(0 sent)P(1 rec | 0 sent) is one of the two terms in (a).